# How to properly config a sub domain site on Forge?

Tags: nginx, laravel-forge

I have read various questions related to this but can't seem to find an appropriate answer.

I have a Forge server that has one site on it.  The site is checked to handle wildcard sub domains.  The domain I am working with is a 3rd party domain that I have requested a sub domain CNAME record be created and pointed to the Forge IP.  This has been done and I can confirm the sub domain does point to the IP.

However, the sub domain throws a ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error.

My nginx config contains this;

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name *.domain.com;
root /home/forge/domain.com/public;
```

Still no luck.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly a **subdomain** is pointed to your server, eg *test.domain.com*. In such case, your code is wrong, it would work for a whole domain. For subdomain try this:

```
server_name sub.domain.com;
```

Or this

```
server_name *.sub.domain.com;
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give that a try.